# add_rewrite_rule no longer working - possible https issue?

Tags: page-template, rewrite-rules

I have a redirect rule that is intended to load a custom template file. This worked last week, and is now not working (and loads a 404 page instead). The only change to the site is the entire site is now loaded on https instead of http.

Here is the function:

```
function event_rewrite() {

    add_rewrite_rule('^event/(.*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=event&event_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'event_rewrite');
```

Is there anything in the matching that would change with https in the url? Or is there a different problem going on that coincidentally arose when we switched to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* be a permalink issue. Sometimes when things like HTTPS get turned on, you need to flush permalinks to get URL's and rewrites working again.

Head to permalinks (settings > permalinks) and just hit the save button and see if that fixes the issue there.

Comment: I tried that earlier, and it didn't work. I tried it again, and it worked. So, let's assume you have the golden touch. Thanks!